# How can I swap those columns, using with Matrix instead of tablix?

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to ask for advice on how to swap those columns?
[image: Swap the columns]

In an essence, my desired result would be:[image]

Using with matrix [image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on top of the *SUM total* column **Insert column -> left**, copy the expression from the most right column. Repeat the steps with the columns *Total, Old, New, Class, Courses*. This way you dont lose your grouping from the column *SUM Total*

Comment: but the grouping won't be the same if I do that.

Comment: You can either **Insert column -> left -> Inside group/outside group** or you rearrange your tablix without the group and in the end you add your grouping again. To add a grouping click on the tablix and on the bottom on the report designer under **Row groups -> (Details) -> click on the arrow -> Add group -> Parent group -> ...**

Comment: because In the leftside, it was group by courseName and right side has no grouping.

Comment: Ok now I think I now what you exactly want. So first create your tablix without grouping (columns: courses, class, new, old, Total [let assume Total = Fields!Total.Value], SUM Total). Group your tablix by the column courses and call the grouping **CoursesGrouping**. Now enter in the **SUM Total** column the expression `=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "CoursesGrouping")`

Comment: How about using matrix instead of tablix?  I feel matrix is more suitable in this case? I've got the desired alignment for texts(especially for sum total) except the cloumn can not be moved to the right end. I've added new picture with using matrix, into my question.

Comment: If you group a tablix by row and column you end up getting a matrix. Normally this way you can design your matrix like you need it. From your picture you need to switch the grouping from the most right to the left Sum Total column (Column groups properties). Then Split the cells in the left column, then switch and copy the expressions. But I would recommend to try it from a tablix, with mergin cells, grouping, totals etc... you end up with your desired matrix. And if you did it once its easyier the next time to design a matrix.

Comment: as you suggest, I make the groupings in the tablix first, my attempt which is the nearest that I can think of is, puting that tablix  inside the matrix to get my SUM Total column. Although the alignment is not so perfect. However it is quite ok running in my designer, no idea of having in the web. Actually I am really out of idea!